# comparar inputs con los valores de un array

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentado de comparar el valor de un `input` con el de un `array`.

Tengo 8 `input` estos tiene que coincidir con cada uno del `array`, ejemplo:

```
input1 == arrayvalor1 && input2 == arrayvalor2
```

Probé con un `indexOf` pero no obtuve el resultado deseado.

```js
let array = ['gato', 'gallo', 'gato', 'perro', 'gallo', 'gato', 'leon', 'perro']

function verificar() {
  let input1 = document.getElementById("inputUno").value
  let input2 = document.getElementById("inputDos").value
  let input3 = document.getElementById("inputTres").value
  let input4 = document.getElementById("inputCuatro").value
  let input5 = document.getElementById("inputCinco").value
  let input6 = document.getElementById("InputSeis").value
  let input7 = document.getElementById("InputSiete").value
  let input8 = document.getElementById("InputOcho").value
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (input1 == array[i] && input2 == array[i] && input3 == array[i] && input4 == array[i] && input5 == array[i] && input6 == array[i] && input7 == array[i] && input8 == array[i]) {
      console.log("entra")
    } else {
      console.log("no entra")
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="inputUno">
  <input type="text" id="inputDos">
  <input type="text" id="inputTres">
  <input type="text" id="inputCuatro">
  <input type="text" id="inputCinco">
  <input type="text" id="InputSeis">
  <input type="text" id="InputSiete">
  <input type="text" id="InputOcho">
  <input type="button" value="Completar" onclick="verificar()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar los valores de las entradas con los valores de la matriz, podes usar una combinación del método `indexOf()` y un bucle. El método `indexOf()` devuelve el índice de la primera aparición de un valor en una matriz, o -1 si el valor no está presente en la matriz.

Te dejo un ejemplo modificando tu código:

```js
let array = ['gato', 'gallo', 'gato', 'perro', 'gallo', 'gato', 'leon', 'perro']

function verificar() {
  let input1 = document.getElementById("inputUno").value;
  let input2 = document.getElementById("inputDos").value;
  let input3 = document.getElementById("inputTres").value;
  let input4 = document.getElementById("inputCuatro").value;
  let input5 = document.getElementById("inputCinco").value;
  let input6 = document.getElementById("InputSeis").value;
  let input7 = document.getElementById("InputSiete").value;
  let input8 = document.getElementById("InputOcho").value;

  let inputs = [input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, input7, input8];

  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (array.indexOf(inputs[i]) === i) {
      console.log("Match found for input " + (i + 1));
    } else {
      console.log("No match found for input " + (i + 1));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="inputUno">
  <input type="text" id="inputDos">
  <input type="text" id="inputTres">
  <input type="text" id="inputCuatro">
  <input type="text" id="inputCinco">
  <input type="text" id="InputSeis">
  <input type="text" id="InputSiete">
  <input type="text" id="InputOcho">
  <input type="button" value="Completar" onclick="verificar()">
</div>
```

Este código recorrerá los valores de la matriz de entradas y comparará cada valor con el valor correspondiente en la matriz mediante el método `indexOf()`. Si el método `indexOf()` devuelve el mismo índice que la variable de bucle `i`, significa que el valor de la entrada coincide con el valor de la matriz.

Saludos.